# Order and Cyclic Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have been trying to solve this multiple question problem, but I am having difficulties discussing if I did each part correctly or not

Given that $G = \mathbb Z_8 \times \mathbb Z_{12}$

1. What is the order of the group G?

I believe that for this I would just multiply $8*12$ to get the order is $96$.

2. What is the order of the element $(2,3) \in G$?

For this one I am not entirely sure on how to do it. I was under the impression I found the $\text{lcm}(4,4) = 4$

3. Show that the order of any element of $G$ divides $24$ and show that there is an element
   of order $24$ in $G$

By finding smallest possible n, such that $(nx,ny) = (0,0)$. Also, if we find the least $n = 96 = |G|$ then $G = \langle (x,y) \rangle$ such that the $\text{ord}(x,y)= 96$. 
We know the least n such that $nx = 0 \in \mathbb Z_8$ would be where $n = 8$. Similarly the least n such that $ny = 0\in \mathbb Z_8 $ is $n = 12$. So if $12|n$ and $8|n$ then it works, and since it does divide then every element of $G$ has order which divides $24$. So G has no element $(x,y)$ of order $96$.

4. Explain why $G$ is not cyclic.

Since it is not generated by a single element and has no element of order $96$ then it is not cyclic.

If I have done anything incorrectly what can I do to improve on my mistakes? Thanks

Comment: For 2) the lcm of the orders is right. Each component has order $4$.

Comment: I edited your question.please see http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics